# Item with published hyperlink field redirects to different page when field is blank SP 2010

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, item-styles

I am currently working on a site in sp 2010. I have a cqwp that displays news items from a list using a custom itemstyle. Each news item has a published hyperlink field used to link off to the source of the article. If a user creates an item with a url in that field, then it works just fine when clicked. Some of these items may not have a url, so the field will be blank. When the field is blank and a user clicks on the item being displayed, they are redirected to a completely different page, when they shouldn't be redirected at all.

This issue only occurs in Internet Explorer. If a user clicks an a displayed item with no url link in Chrome, they are not redirected from the page.

Comment: Resolved using some javascript to make the news item not redirect if the link field was blank.